# Sharepoint files restriction

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Been working on the SharePoint site for some time and got these questions:

*How to keep files secure for different people.
In one folder there will be 500 excel files. Each one must be locked down to just specific people. No one should see anyone else's file.
What are the options and what is the most efficient to manage considering a large number of users?*

What would be the best option to solve this? I know permission level can be used to give and restrict access to documents uploaded in SharePoint but I do not think it is possible to restrict access to files e.g. file a - belongs to person a, therefore person b, c, d .... cannot access it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are several scenario about A can access a file B cannot:

See draft items in a list or library:

1. List settings -> Versioning Settings -> Content Approval -> Yes
   When files upload, it would be in draft status
2. List settings -> Versioning Settings -> Draft Item Security
   You could set it to ‘Only user who can approve items’. Then only author or with approve permission can access the draft items.

Change view:

You could change the view to filter the files.
Add the filter ‘create by’, for example add a filter ‘create by’ ‘A’, it would not see the  files create by others.

Single file access:

You could set single file access in library.
Select a file -> more -> detail -> manage access.